# Primefaces dynamic overlayPanel without internally rendering rest of page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

We are using Primefaces 5.09 with JSF 2.1.2 on a Wildlfy 8.1.0 Final

We have a datatable with a lot of content which consumes quite an amount of time to load (which is ok as it is)
In every row we have a commandLink refering to a dynamically loaded overlayPanel which is defined in a composition:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:panelGroup>
        <p:commandLink id="CID" title="#{messageId}" type="button" value="#{messageId}" ajax="true" actionListener="#{SyncClientPopupBean.setSyncClientById(messageId)}" update="grid" disabled="#{not Shiro.isPermitted('admin:syncclient:read')}" />

        <p:overlayPanel for="CID" dynamic="true" at="right top" my="left bottom" appendTo="@(body)">
            <p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" styleClass="ui-datatable-auto-width">
                  <...../>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:overlayPanel>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

The Ajax request itself works fine, as the result only contains the content for the overlayPanel.
Our Problem now is, that the update on the overlayPanel also seems to internally render the rest of the page as it is loading the items for the datatable etc.
Therefore requesting this very small content for the panel takes about as long as loading the whole datatable.

The Backing Beans for the whole Page and the overlay are already separated.

Is there any possibility to get Primefaces to render only this single component?

Comment: So every single row has such an overlay panel? And there is never more than one opened at the same time? If so, why not just using only one outside the table whose content is dynamically updated based on the selected row?

Comment: At the moment it is rendered to every row. Would it solve my problem if i put one overlayPanel outside the datatable? If so i will see if i find a suitable solution. The point is, that this is used as a composition across more than one datatable. But if putting it outside is the only solution i will have to split it into two compositions

Comment: I have tried to use a single overlayPanel as well as a dialog outside the datatable. Even if i put them in an extra form and tell the commandLink to only process the one with the dialog the data fpr the datatable gets accessed. It seems that Primefaces renders (or at least loads) the datatable in every ajax request no matter if needed or not